# Cusom button in prime-ng DynamicDialog footer

Tags: angular, primeng

PrimeNG, Angular 17.

I have a custom button, 'Change State', on DynamicDialog Footer template. Dialog works great, buttons events are working on the footer template. However, I would like to forward call from DialogFooter.changeState() to DialogComponent.changeState() function. I am not able to figure out how to add a custom listener on DynamicDialogRef component. My hack would be to create a service and setup a EventEmitter subject which I am sure will work. I am trying to see if there is any elegant way to do this.

Footer template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'footer',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        ButtonModule
    ],
    template:  `
    <p-button
        type="button" 
        label="Save" 
        icon="pi pi-save" 
        severity="success"
        (click)="closeDialog({ buttonType: 'Save', summary: 'Record saved' })"
        class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-success"
        [disabled]="isDisabled"/>
    <p-button 
        type="button" 
        label="Cancel" 
        icon="pi pi-times" 
        severity="danger"
        (click)="closeDialog({ buttonType: 'Cancel', summary: 'No record saved' })"
        class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-info"></p-button>
    <p-button
        type="button" 
        label="Change State" 
        icon="pi pi-edit" 
        severity="success"
        (click)="changeState()"
        class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-success"/> `
})
export class DialogFooter {
    constructor(public ref: DynamicDialogRef,
        private config:DynamicDialogConfig) {}
    isDisabled:boolean = false;

    closeDialog(data:any) {
        this.ref.close(data);
    }

    changeState() {
        console.log("Change state");
    }
}
```

Dialog Component.ts

export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

```
isDisabled:boolean = false;

constructor(private recService: RecordService, 
            private dialogService: DialogService, 
            private ref: DynamicDialogRef,
            private config:DynamicDialogConfig) {}

ngOnInit() {
}

closeDialog(data:any) {
    this.ref.close(data);
}
changeState() {
  this.isDisabled=!this.isDisabled;
  // This should be called from DialogFooter
}
```

I am using isDisabled attribute in the dialog to enable/disable input elements.

```
        <input pInputText id="zoneName" [(ngModel)]="rec.name" [disabled]="isDisabled"/>
```

Cheers

Edits added:

Added rookie solution :) with my limited knowledge.

In Calling Component:

```
  export class ZonesComponent implements OnInit {
       @Output() emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
       ....

       showDialog() {
           this.ref = this.dialogService.open(
                           ZoneDialogComponent, {
                            data: {
                                id: id,
                                emitter: this.emitter},
               .....
           });

       }
```

Listen to Event in Dialog Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.config.data.emitter.subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log("Received emitter event. " + data);
      this.changeState();
    });
}
```

Generate event from Footer and forward it to Dialog Component

```
export class DialogFooter {

    changeState() {
        console.log("Change state");
        this.config.data.emitter.emit("test");
        console.log("Even sent!");
    }
}
```

This works well so far.